# RSS-Parse get attribute from item

Tags: node.js, rss

I'm parsing a rss with rss-parse in nodejs and I want to get an attribute of a specific item like url:

`<media:thumbnail url="https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/lR-w1h5ONOY/hqdefault.jpg" width="480" height="360"/>`

I get the media:thumbnail object but I don't know how to get the url.

My code is:

```
(async () => {

    let feed = await parser.parseURL(RSS_URL);
    console.log(feed.title);
  
    feed.items.forEach(item => {
         console.log("media:thumbnail: ", item['media:group']['media:thumbnail']);              
    });
  
  })();
```

The object is returned

```
media:thumbnail:  [
  {
    '$': {
      url: 'https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/NUsXWhus_50/hqdefault.jpg',
      width: '480',
      height: '360'
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing from the object you provided, you could try accesing `url` like that:

```js
item['media:group']['media:thumbnail'][0]['$'].url
```